# How to get Specific Element of Style by code in Wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, datatemplate, controltemplate

Hi I'm trying to use a template item into the code behind c#

I'm trying to access the PictureBox which is WindowsFormHost.
And then set it to what I want.

```
<Style x:Key="ScreenListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="-0.001,0" Background="#FFABABAB" Width="120" Height="117">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="stackPanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="TestStackPanel" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
                            <Grid Margin="3" Height="85" Name="TestGrid" Background="White">
                                <WindowsFormsHost Name="wrapper" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                                    <Forms:PictureBox Name="Picture"></Forms:PictureBox>
                                </WindowsFormsHost>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Margin="0" Width="Auto" Opacity="0">
                                    <DockPanel Margin="0" Width="Auto" Height="45">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFD8D8D8" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFEBE77A" Margin="0" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF60CDE9" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF60E98E" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFC65F9C" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFC43232" Margin="0" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF0A37A5" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" Width="Auto">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF0A37A5" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFC65F9C" Margin="0" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF60CDE9" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Margin="0" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFD8D8D8" Margin="0" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0" FontWeight="Bold" Width="60" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="9.333"/>
                                    </DockPanel>

                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Margin="5,0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappingStyle}"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <Button Content="Button" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource Edit}"/>
                                <Path x:Name="path" Data="F1M29.2007,72.9482L25.9947,75.2372L25.9947,73.7922L18.5627,73.7922L18.5627,78.9302L25.9947,78.9302L25.9947,77.4862L29.2007,79.7752z" Fill="#FF231F20" Height="9.327" Stretch="Fill" Width="14.534" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF231F20" Margin="0" Width="20" Height="20" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height, VerticalMargin" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="path" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A1E5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Whenever I use this style in C# I do :

```
var listboxitem = new ToggleButton();

listboxitem.Style = (Style)FindResource("ScreenListBox");

VideoListBox.Items.Add(listboxitem);
```

//Here I want to be able to use the PictureBox in ScreenListBox.

To pass it to another function.

I've been trying with Template.FindName and it didn't work.

Could anyone have a look and try to bring me into the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Uff.... I didn't see there's a winforms stuff in there... What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Hi HighCore, the winform is there to be able to get a Handle of a control.

And then pass it to some pvinvoke stuff to be able to show win32 stuff in that control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I guess only one way to implement this will be to create a custom Control which you can inherit form ToggleButton. Somewhere you should define control template for your control (like generic.xaml or App.xaml). In your custom control you should override OnApplyTemplate method, where you can get access at least to the WindowsFormsHost (but maybe to PictureBox as well) with FindName method.

You can also try to use your code, before you will try to get access to PictureBox - try to invoke ApplyTemplate, maybe this will force ToggleButton to load everything and it will give you access to it's children.